# PHP Regular expression to clean up empty <a>tags</a>

Tags: php, regex

Using a WYSIWYG HTML editor in one of my sites there is an ahref cleaner the strips out bad href= urls but what it is leaving behind for each cleaned instance is.

```
<a>some text here</a>
```

There are sometimes more than one in the text block so what I am looking for is a preg_replace _all expression that will leave intact any `<a href-"...">`  but will clean out the above example.

ie. `<a>some text here</a>`

will become `some text here`

Basically I need to run this on a large blocks of code going in and/or coming out of DB.

Thanks.

Comment: HTML with potentially malformed tags or missing close tag should not be processed with regex.

Comment: Consider using `DOMDocument` or `tidy` to clean HTML instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try and keep it simple:

```
$result = preg_replace('%<a>(.*?)</a>%s', '\1', $subject);
```

This assumes that there actually is a matching `</a>` tag for every `<a>` tag, and that they are not nested (which they shouldn't be anyway).